# Getting Cannot read property 'style' of undefined error in javascript

Tags: javascript, typescript

Getting Cannot read property 'style' of undefined error in javascript with the following code actually everything is working fine in local when I am updating it on the server it's showing the above-mentioned error.

```
var currentTab = 0;
        showTab(currentTab);

        function showTab(n) {
          var x = document.getElementsByClassName("tab");
          x[n].style.display = "block"; // on this line I am getting error
          if (n == 0) {
            document.getElementById("prevBtn").style.display = "none";
          } else {
            document.getElementById("prevBtn").style.display = "inline";
          }
          if (n == (x.length - 1)) {
            document.getElementById("nextBtn").innerHTML = "Submit";
          } else {
            document.getElementById("nextBtn").innerHTML = "Next";
          }
          fixStepIndicator(n)
        }
```

Comment: Well, this could happen because the `prevBtn` or any of the `tab` class elements don't existsin the server page when this function is called.

Comment: getting error here x[n].style.display = "block"; not on button block

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure your code executed after the the x[n] element is added to the dom.
Execute your code inside DOMContentLoaded or jQuery(ready) events. You will find lots of examples on the net.

Comment: Yes! thanks a lot!! code must enclose into this ->      document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {       


});